# C++ XOR encryption - decryption issue

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, xor

I followed a tutorial on stephan-brumme website for XOR encryption (unfortunately I cannot include URL because I do not have enough reputation). What I want to do is following: read the content of example.txt file and decrypt the text that it includes. For example, this is the content of example.txt:

```
\xe7\xfb\xe0\xe0\xe7
```

This, when decrypted using password "password" should return "hello". This is the code I got:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

std::string decode(const std::string& input)
{
  const size_t passwordLength = 9;
  static const char password[passwordLength] = "password";
  std::string result = input;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    result[i] ^= ~password[i % passwordLength];
  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << decode(line);
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And this is the result of running the application:
[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdEKE.png)

As you can see, the decryption was not successful. Now, if I make it so it doesn't read the .txt, but directly decrypts the text, like this:

```
cout << decode("\xe7\xfb\xe0\xe0\xe7");
```

It works perfectly:
[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht3mE.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: most likely source is the contents of example.txt. Remember the output of XOR is in binary format, which means example.txt needs to be UTF-8. For sake of consistency, always stick with key and input of same type [Ex: char or widechar(utf-8)]

Comment: example.txt is UTF-8. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: can u include an image that shows the contents of the file?

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://i.imgur.com/dzc9nBh.png

Comment: remove "\x" from the file contents and read the file as ascii.

Comment: ok, and what tool did you use to display the contents of the file?

Comment: I used Notepad++. The "hello" is encrypted that way it is readable, so that it doesn't contain strange symbols. I don't know how to explain the way it is encrypted because I can't post links (I would post the link referring to the tutorial I used).

Comment: This is the tutorial I followed: http://create.stephan-brumme.com/hide-strings-executable/

Comment: @Nandu I tried that, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character XOR by same character is zero, so the result may include zero. `std::string` doesn't like that because zero terminates the string.

You also can use `std::vector<char>` instead of `std::string` for the actual encoding/decoding. You would have to change the `decode` function to handle `vector<char>`

And read/write the file in binary.

Edit: Using `std::string` only, and `std::string decode(const std::string& input)`

```
int main()
{
    std::string line = "hello";

    {
        line = decode(line);
        std::ofstream myfile("example.txt", std::ios::binary);
        myfile.write(line.data(), line.size());

        //Edit 2 *************
        //std::cout << std::hex;
        //for (char c : line)
        //  std::cout << "\\x" << (0xff & c);
        //*************
        //This will make sure width is always 2
        //For example, it will print "\x01\x02" instead of "\x1\x2"
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
        for (char c : line)
            std::cout << "\\x" << std::setw(2) << (0xff & c);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::ifstream myfile("example.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        int filesize = (int)myfile.tellg();
        line.resize(filesize);
        myfile.seekg(0);
        myfile.read(&line[0], filesize);
        line = decode(line);
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string` can hold NUL characters just fine (its C strings that have trouble with NULs), so there's no need to use a `vector`.  The problem (which you solve) is that `getline` can't deal with NULs, plus if the newlines are encrypted, `getline` won't be able to find them, so you need to use binary reads.

Comment: This is working fine, but I need to have the "hello" encrypted in a readable way. I mean, I need it to be like \xe7\xfb\xe0\xe0\xe7 and not like that: http://i.imgur.com/tne1I7T.png
Is this possible?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @ChrisDodd you are right. `std::string` terminate sometimes, for example when seeing "abc\0123", I usually stay away from it when zero is involved. But in this case it should be fine. I'll edit the answer to show just `std::string`

Comment: This is the tutorial I followed: http://create.stephan-brumme.com/hide-strings-executable/
Is it possible to make it so that the "hello" will be encrypted in the format like in this tutorial and not using unreadable symbols?
Thank you!

Comment: @MrWhite, just format the output. See updated answer.

Comment: I get the following error: http://i.imgur.com/MRlSzSA.png on this line: 
input[i] ^= password[i % passwordLength];

Comment: You can't assign to elements of input - it's const.  Use result[i] = input[i] ^ password[i%passwordLength];

Comment: I changed the answer, so now it's using the original decode function. Put your own decode function which is listed in the question.

Comment: Great. There is one thing I forgot. If the number is less than 16 (0xFF), the print format will be `"\x1\x2"` but I think the format should be `"\x01\x02"`. So we need to format with `std::setfill('0')` and `std::setw(2)` It would also need the header `#include <iomanip>` See updated answer again (Edit 2)

Answer (score 1):

I bet example.txt contains the characters '\', 'x', 'e', '7' etc.  You have to read those, process all the backslash escapes, and *then* feed it to decode.

\xe7 is a common way of representing a *single* character with hex value E7.  (Which is quite likely to be the single character 'ç' depending on your character set).  If you want to store (encrypted) readable text, I suggest dropping the \x, and having the file contain lines like "e7fbe0e0e7".  Then 
 - read each line into a string. 
 - Convert each pair of characters from a hex number into an integer, and store the result in a char.
 - Store that char in the string.
 - Then xor decrypt the string.

Alternatively, ensure the file contains the actual binary characters you need it to.

Also beware that you are XOR-ing with the terminating nul byte of the password.  Did you mean to do that?

Comment: I'm all for downvoting bad answers - but help me improve; tell me *what* was bad about my answer.

Comment: Yes, it does include those characters. Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "process all the backslash escapes, and then feed it to decode". Can you be more specific please? Thank you very much for trying to help!

Comment: \xe7 is a common way of representing a *single* character with hex value E7.  (Which is quite likely to be the single character 'ç' depending on your character set).  If you want to store (encrypted) readable text, I suggest dropping the \x, and having the file contain lines like "e7fbe0e0e7"

Comment: And then, after I read the file I could just add the slashes and it should work?

Comment: The slashes don't exist.  They are not characters in the string.  A string written as "\xe7\xe8" is TWO characters long.  Just as "\r\n" is two characters.  On the other hand "/xe7/xe8" is eight characters long. ... and to get a C++ program to display those 8 characters with backslashes, you'd have to write cout << "\\xe7\\xe8"

Comment: Thank you for the nice clarification, I get it now but I don't have idea how could I encrypt the data without the "/x".